# How can I show only "hour" and "minute" in <g:datepicker/> grails and groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy, datepicker

How can I show only "hour" and "minute" in  grails and groovy? I don,t want to show date, I want to show only "hour" and "minute". Please help me quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, `<g:datepicker>` shows each component of the date (year, month, day, etc.) in a separate HTML `<select>`. So the simplest solution is to hide the year, month, day selects with CSS, e.g.

```
#day, #month, #year {
  display: none
}
```

you'll need to replace `#day, #month, #year` with a selector that selects the day, month and year HTML selects.

Comment: <g:datePicker id="myDate" name="myDate" precision="minute" noSelection="['':'-Choose-']" value="${myDate.format('hh:mm')}" />   Like that?? But I face "Cannot invoke method format() on null object" problem.. Please advice me.. Thank you so much

Comment: Could you give me the example source code to hide the year, month, day selects with CSS. Thz